# why my form_validation doesn't work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I to show a message if a user enters an English character. The message should display that a Persian character must be entered. I use a callback function for this, but when I fill in an English character it doesn't show the message (`please enter %s in persian.`).

This is my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>mantaghe<span style="color:red">*</span></label> 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-1">
            <input class="form-control" id="mantaghe" name="mantaghe"></input>
            <?php echo form_error('mantaghe'); ?>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
public function show_info()
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('mantaghe', 'mantaghe ',                     
   'required|callback_persian_check');
}
function persian_check()
{       
    $username = $this->input->post('mantaghe');
    if (!preg_match('/^[^\x{600}-\x{6FF}]+$/u',$username))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('persian_check'," please enter %s in persian");
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: You write **method inside method** write your method after complete first one and access with `$this->METHODNAME` and add more information about your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as below

```
function persian_check()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('mantaghe');
    if (!preg_match('/^[آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی]/',$username))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('persian_check'," please enter %s in persian");
            return false;
         }
            else
                return true;
}
```

Comment: I have it، but doesn't work I just put a part of my code.